# Am I understand this problem correct: learning thory, break point, vc dimension

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, self-study, information-theory

The problem is:

> Consider the “triangle” learning model, where $h : R^2 → \{−1, +1\}$ and $h(x) = +1$ if $x$ lies within an arbitrarily chosen triangle in the plane and $−1$ otherwise. Which is the largest number of points in $R^2$(among the given choices) that can be shattered by this hypothethesis set?

The answer is: $9$.

After drawing something like below, it matches with the answer, but I don't know if it is correct. Is there any other solution to this?

[image]

Comment: The question states "among the given choices" -- what are the given choices? Also, your picture seems to show a case where 9 points are *not* shattered by $h$.

Comment: Hi @chang_trenton, others are 1,3,5,7,9

Comment: I think in the course of caltech, the teacher is using `break point` which is vc dimentsion +1.